# How can I use the bus created with the bus editor in my Simulink model?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I was reading this article:
http://www.mathworks.nl/help/simulink/ug/using-the-bus-editor.html

I found out how I can export the created bus to a .mat file or a an .m file. However, I want to use the bus I created with the bus editor in my existing Simulink model. For example, it would be really nice to create this bus with the bus editor:

http://www.mathworks.nl/help/simulink/ug/bus_editor_nested_objects.png

and someway use it to create this simulink model:
http://www.mathworks.nl/help/simulink/ug/bus_editor_nested_model.png

They basically means the same but it is not (clearly) explained how to transfer the created bus to a simulink model.

If you know (another) way to use a bus, created with the bus editor in a simulink model this will probably also help me. I like the bus I created with the bus editor, but I need it in my simulink model not to create matlab code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: create the bus objects in the Base Workspace.  Your image (http://www.mathworks.nl/help/simulink/ug/bus_editor_nested_objects.png) indicates that you have done this.

Step 2: tell the bus creator blocks that their output data type should be an object of the appropriate bus type.  To do this open the bus creator's dialog (by double clicking on it) and then near the bottom there is a pull-down selection box that should show all bus object in the base workspace - select the appropriate one.  Do this for both your main and control bus creator blocks.